# Recommend cloud options for linux VM instance?

Tags: linux, virtual-machines, cloud-hosting

I'm the teaching assistant for a CS class in the spring and wanted to investigate low cost cloud options for hosting smallish footprint (512 MB or 1 GB ram) linux instances that students can telnet into.  Ideally it would support remote desktop access for KDE or a similar environment.

The tooling on the boxes would be the gcc and java compilers, with Eclipse if GUI access is possible.  Cost is the main consideration though reliability is nice too...thanks!

Comment: FYI, they should be using ssh not telnet at this point.

Comment: Shopping Questions and product recommendations are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q and A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 1):

First, check if the actual university, college or institution has an internal/private cloud offering...

Next, have you considered [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/)?

In either case, you would be the one to provide the remote desktop option on the resulting platform. [NoMachine](http://www.nomachine.com/) is a good option for this.

Answer (score 1):

you could try instacompute.com. They may be cheaper than amazon and dare say more reliable! er.. hello netflix :)